# Why does applying system-wide network proxy settings affect only the superuser (root)?

Tags: networking, proxy, wget

I recently solved my problem [How to check if Network Proxy is really applied?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3807/how-to-check-network-proxy-is-really-applied) 
Now I can use `sudo apt-get install application-name` easily - but the problem is that the normal user (not the superuser) cannot see the proxy.

For example, these commands have different outputs:

`wget http://whatismyip.com`

and

`sudo wget http://whatismyip.com`

It shows that the first command does not use the proxy while the second clearly says:

> Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.

the strange thing is that when I check http://whatismyip.com with Firefox, it shows the proxy IP not my real IP, which means that Firefox sees the proxy.

Why can't **wget** see the proxy?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check that after doing `Apply System-wide...` that the following things happen :

1. the file /etc/environment has entries with the proxy settings you specified.
2. Any terminal program launched **after** closing the `Network proxy` dialog has the proxy variables set in their environment ?

   ```
   set | grep -i proxy
   ```

   should give you entries like this

   ```
   https_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
   http_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
   ftp_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
   ```

wget as per [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Proxies) would use these proxies. I have it working at my laptop at work.

Are you sure, you have provided the wget command to a terminal process that was launched after the `Network Proxy` dialog was closed ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may actually be [bug 232469](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wget/+bug/232469), which has some proposed fixes and workarounds. One of them seems to be to edit `/etc/wgetrc` as root, and scroll down to where you see this:

```
# You can set the default proxies for Wget to use for http, https, and ftp.
# They will override the value in the environment.
#https_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
#http_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
#ftp_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
```

Uncomment (remove the #) and set the proxies you want to use. Save and close. This should set global wget-specific settings for all users, and should be an adequate workaround until the bug is resolved.

You can also add these settings to `~/.wgetrc` and it will take effect on a per-user basis.

Comment: thanks for the note. i was made directly change proxy setting for apt-get too. so i should specify network proxy for each application separately. i think the Proxy Network is completely useless in Ubuntu.

Comment: The Network Proxy app sets GNOME proxy settings, so yes, it only applies to applications which use them.

Comment: i don't like editing `/etc/wgetrc/` as i would make to edit it again if i reinstalled ubuntu. is there any alternative file to edit in `/home` ?

Comment: You can edit/create ~/.wgetrc and add the same settings, they will just only apply to your user and not root. Which should be fine for this situation.

Comment: In the bug report Jacob mentions, [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wget/+bug/232469/comments/31) and the next one are worth taking a look.