# Network proxy is not applied

Tags: networking, package-management, proxy

I'm trying to make the Update Manager work through the proxy on my ubuntu 9.10. I've tried what was suggested [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3807/how-to-check-network-proxy-is-really-applied), but the Update Manager still reports 409 conflict. Would really appreciate if anybody could help me with this.

The window manager solution turned out to simple: System->Administration->Synaptic package manager, then in the Synaptic window Settings->Preferences->Network. Manually enter the http_proxy field. And it works now. Still am curious as to how to do this from command line though.

Comment: 2 questions to make me understand your question better. 1. what is a 409 conflict ? 2. Are you unable to download packages via proxy even after creating `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/40proxy` as explained in the post you have referred ? (If you clicked "Apply system-wide..." in `Network Proxy` after creating that file, it may get deleted)

Comment: 2. yes, I'm unable to download packages after following your suggestions in that post. And yes, the file is there.

Comment: 1. No, I'm unable to download packages. When I start the Update Manager, Click "check", type the password, it fails to download anything and pops up an err window "Could not download all repository indexes". There it lists individual packages, like this: "Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic/partner/binary-i386/Packages.gz  409  Conflict [IP: <ip here> 80]"

Comment: @Zhenya can you successfully run `apt-get update` from the terminal?  or do you get the same HTTP 409 error?

Comment: @Riccardo Murri: same error, Err http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Packages
  409  Conflict "

Comment: @Zhenya and from the browser?  Can you download the erroring URL?

Comment: @Riccardo Murri: The browser works fine. In fact, the solution turned out to be rather simple, see the edit. Thanks for your suggestions anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Proxy configuration in `update-manager` apparently happens at lines 179--228 of file `/usr/share/pyshared/UpdateManager/Core/utils.py` (checked on Lucid, line numbers and file name may be different on other versions).  Despite what the comment say, the code looks for proxy settings in this order:

1. the `Acquire::http::Proxy` setting in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`
2. The `Synaptic::useProxy`, `Synaptic::httpProxy`, `Synaptic::httpProxyPort` settings in `/root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf`
3. the `/system/http_proxy/*` settings in gconf

The first one found *sets* the `http_proxy` environment variable for children processes (i.e., the ones that actually perform the update/upgrade).

Therefore, my advice would be to try adding this line to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxyhost.example.org:8080/";
```

The exact syntax is documented in the [apt.conf(5) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/apt.conf)

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion! Actually, I tried adding this line to /etc/apt/apt.conf before asking here. Right now the line is there (I recall I had to create the file manually), and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to modify .bashrc?
Something like that:

```
$ sudo echo "export http_proxy=http://user:pass@ProxyAddress:ProxyPort" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
$ sudo echo "export ftp_proxy=ftp://user:pass@ProxyAddress:ProxyPort" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: yes, http_proxy and ftp_proxy env variables are set