# How to run "sudo apt-get update" through proxy in commandline?

Tags: networking

In my office i want to update and download through (wget) and here they are using proxy?

How can i do this by commandline?

Comment: Also see [How to install packages with apt-get on a system connected via proxy?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3144/9812

Answer (score 124):

In some releases sudo is configured in such a way that all environment variables all cleared when running the command. To keep the value for your **http_proxy** and fix this, you need to edit /etc/sudoers, run:

```
visudo
```

Then find a line that states:

```
Defaults env_reset
```

and add after it:

```
Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy ftp_proxy"
```

Things will start working as expected.

Thanks to **kdogksu** in the Ubuntu Forums for finding the [solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9845413&postcount=5) for this.

In order to not only fix apt-get but also graphical X11 utils as e.g synaptic,mintintall, ...) the following line in `/etc/sudoers` should do the job :

```
Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy DISPLAY XAUTHORITY"
```

Comment: Would it be necessary to add "https_proxy" too?

Comment: $ export http_proxy="http://user:password@proxy-server:port"  and if your password contains special characters --http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-export-variable-http_proxy-with-special-characters/

Comment: should 'env_keep' be added after 'env_reset' or placed in its place? They look opposing to each other, so is there sense in keeping both?

Comment: Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy DISPLAY XAUTHORITY" worked for me ! Thanks ! -

Comment: Stumbled on this after lots of browsing. This solved my problem.

Comment: Any idea how this can be done without root privileges?

Comment: I recommend using `Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy rsync_proxy no_proxy"` to catch more of the proxy related environment variables.

Comment: Yeah, this is dangerously wrong. Root should only be using the `http_proxy` and related variables for `apt`, not wrapping the entire root session for everyone. See John Cartwright's answer about setting the proxy in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or a file under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`

Answer (score 58):

Use this.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://Username:Password@proxy.foo.bar.edu.au:8080";
```

This is what I use. Works perfectly.

Apt also allows individual settings to be placed in files under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, so this has exactly the same effect as the above, but may be easier to maintain if you have other lines in the `.conf` file:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/05proxy
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://Username:Password@proxy.foo.bar.edu.au:8080";
```

Comment: I recommend editing this to explain how to add that line to the configuration file. Attempting to run those lines on the command-line won't do it. Right now this answer is based on a correct idea but won't be helpful to a novice. It's not even entirely clear that you're saying that line *should be added* to `apt.conf`.

Comment: awesome !!!! works like charm

Comment: On my system I had to create a file under /etc/apt/apt.conf.d but small detail - worked great

Comment: @dldnh: You can create the file ```/etc/apt/apt.conf``` or use place a config file in ```/etc/apt/apt.conf.d```....either works! :-)

Comment: don't forget the semicolon or you'll get `E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:2: Extra junk at end of file`

Comment: It firms up the answer to direct the user to a single option.

Comment: Ubuntu 18 LTS... file? /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`xx.yy`? (`05proxy` not exists)

Answer (score 43):

The thing that worked for me was:

```
sudo http_proxy=http://yourserver apt-get update
```

Which is a bit odd because simply exporting http_proxy and then running sudo echo $http_proxy obediently printed out the exported value

Comment: `$http_proxy` gets expanded before sudo even gets run.

Comment: This worked great in a Dockerfile!

Comment: Don't forget the port for the proxy if required :)

Answer (score 17):

```
export http_proxy=http://proxyusername:proxypassword@proxyaddress:proxyport
sudo apt-get update
```

The export shouldn't need `sudo`ing and if your proxy is anonymous, just ditch the `proxyusername:proxypassword@` part.

Comment: :-( , I am getting error "Access to web proxy service denied!"

Comment: Do the same proxy settings work for something simple like `wget`?

Comment: yes ..the same error repeating...

Comment: What about editing /etc/apt/apt.conf  with Acquire::http::Proxy "http://MYDOMAIN\MYNAME:MYPASS@MY.PROXY.COM:MYPORT" ?

Comment: You can also add this to your ~/.bashrc.  Horrible security risk though.

Comment: re @Renjith comment, to help others, one can also use MYDOMAIN via the http_proxy command : `export http_proxy="http://MYDOMAIN\proxyusername:proxypassword@proxyaddress:proxyport"` (And re @Oli, inverted commas are required I believe)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to run “sudo apt-get update” through proxy in commandline, use below command,

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::proxy="http://user:password@host:port/" update;
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try editing `/etc/apt/apt.conf`? I use this to use apt behind our corporate proxy.

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:password@host:port/";
```

I believe that apt uses this value unless $http_proxy is defined in your shell environment (i.e. $http_proxy takes precedence).

Comment: I'm not sure apt.conf is still in use... When I updated from 8.04 to 10.04 I ended up with impossible update, until I got rid of the proxy settings in that file - then the proxy settings set in Synaptic started to work again...

Comment: That's odd - I use apt.conf with 10.04. I find the settings in this file are separate from those configured in the Synaptic package manager preferences gui.

Comment: Yes, `apt.conf` should still be used. You can see what configuration settings apt thinks it has set by using `apt-config dump`.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu is incredibly hostile to authenticating proxies.  I use an Ubuntu laptop at work and the number of breakages is incredible.

Synaptic, Apt, Firefox, Chromium, etc all use different methods for specifying a proxy and there's nowhere to specify credentials securely.

Some bugs on the subject :
https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/220070

https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-cacher/+bug/198138

https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/433827

https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/b43-fwcutter/+bug/683630

Oli's suggestion to use an export is the only vaguely secure way to do it.  It's also sometimes possible to "fudge" proxy support if the proxy server is using secondary authentication to minimise load on the main authentication servers (say perhaps Active Directory).  This is where the first proxy connection is authenticated by the proxy against AD, then for a set time period (usually 5 minutes) all other connections are "trusted" to be that user.  Therefore, you can open firefox, browse the internet (anywhere will do), then try your utility (wget, synaptic, whatever) by specifying a proxy, but leave the username blank.

Ubuntu is generally hostile to any corporate environment simply because it allows passwords to be read so easily.  Seahorse is a prime culprit, but Network Manager is also shocking - connect to any PEAP authenticated network and you've just stored your password in the applet for anyone to see who might borrow your laptop.  Apparently laptop sharing is considered sacrilege in Linux land, since Seahorse developers rejected claims of insecurity.  After that, I didn't have the heart to contact the network-manager devs.

Comment: I recommend cntlm as a cure for this. It handles authenticating with AD and you set all of your proxy settings to use 127.0.0.1 without requiring any credentials.

Comment: If you need to authenticate with another machine then the password plaintext needs to be stored. "encryption" wouldn't add any security, because the encryption key needs to be stored on the same device in order for the passwords to be available.

Comment: Jeremy, you're taking the same on/off approach to security as the Seahorse devs. I'm not saying to make this stuff impossible, just make it hard. Right now, stealing credentials from an unlocked Ubuntu laptop is trivial - maybe five clicks and you've got it. The same is not true of Windows - it might still be possible, but even I wouldn't know how to do it. There is no simple way to lift a password from a Windows machine in the 10 minutes or so you might leave a workstation unlocked by accident. Do the same in Ubuntu and you might as well hand in your resignation. It's not good enough.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a **temporary configuration**, you could try this:
sudo bash -c 'http_proxy="http://< proxy_host >:< proxy_port >/" apt-get update'

You need this, because the environment variable needs to be defined for the "root" account. Doing and export before should not work.

For a **permanent configuration**, you will have to modify a system file. This is already described in the following answer about [How to check Network proxy is really applied?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3807/how-to-check-network-proxy-is-really-applied/3808#3808).

Comment: :-( , I am getting error "Access to web proxy service denied!"

Comment: You probably have to enter a login and password, do you? If so http_proxy should have the form "http://< user >:< pass >@< host >:< port >/"