# how to install packages with apt-get on a system connected via proxy?

Tags: apt, package-management, proxy

I've got an Ubuntu 11.10 system connected via a proxy to the internet, and I would like to install packages via apt-get. When I try to do that I get this error message:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-program-options-dev
[...]
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main libboost1.46-dev i386 1.46.1-5ubuntu2
407  Proxy Authentication Required
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is their any free proxy details available so that i can connect and download some packages @ my office.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This method worked for me.....just have a try...

check the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

The contents were,

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<proxy>:<port>/";
```

This was the reason why you could reach proxy but couldn't get past it, since there is no username password information. So just put that info into it..

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/";
```

save the file and you are done...

---

BROTIP: More better add these lines in another file, `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80proxy`. This will ensure that after a version upgrade changes won't be lost.

Comment: <br> What if in the username there is a "@" char. <br>
For example if the username is a complete email address?

Comment: @Hunger, refer this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-export-variable-http_proxy-with-special-characters/.

Comment: if you doing this in the morning, don't forget to delete the chevrons

Comment: Acquire::socks::proxy "socks5://server:port";

Answer (score 51):

To configure a proxy temporary, set the `http_proxy` environment variable. If the proxy is `proxy.example.com` on port `8080` and you need to authenticate with username `user` and password `pass`, run:

```
sudo http_proxy='http://user:pass@proxy.example.com:8080/' apt-get install package-name
```

To set such a proxy permanently, create `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/30proxy` containing:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:pass@proxy.example.com:8080/";
```

The changes are immediately visible the next time you run apt.

Comment: It's still not working, same error. I should mention I have my proxy set up globally on `Applications -> System Tools -> System Settings -> Network Proxy -> Apply system Wide`

Comment: The proxy connection works for me (tested with netcat as well as Squid). What proxy server is in use? Some proxies may need other authentication methods.

Comment: +1 temporary workaround was a more suitable answer for me!

Comment: @Lekensteyn : why did you choose the '30' prefix? i now it define the order of parsing, but: is there a convention about 30 for proxy?

Comment: @jgomo3 I probably looked at the other files (or a README in that directory if it exists?) and then picked a value at random. The files are read in alphabetical order.

Comment: What's the difference between having proxy config in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` vs `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/30proxy`.

Comment: @Behrang Both are treated by APT as the same thing, but having a separate config file for its purpose makes it easier to disable/enable it.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use Synaptics Package Manager, setting in its Preferences the proxy to which you want to connect. You can find the configuration using this path:
Settings -> Preferences -> Network