# Proxy setttings not working in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, proxy

I always use a proxy to connect to the internet in Windows as well as in previous versions of Ubuntu, but in Ubuntu 11.10 it seems that the proxy settings I set in the GUI are not being applied system-wide.

I can access the internet in Firefox with its own proxy settings.  I can access internet in the terminal (i.e. I am able to use apt-get for some small programs).  But in Ubuntu software centre or update manager it is not working.

Comment: I have the same problem - if I set manual proxy settings in Firefox, I can access the internet, but if I set it to use the system proxy settings (even though they're the same!), connections just time out.

Comment: I have the same issues but after reading <a href="http://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy">this </a> it worked. The link is :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy
Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem when I first installed Ubuntu 11.10.  I don't know which of the following steps solved it, but this is what I did:

- Open a terminal
- Run `export HTTP_PROXY=http://<myproxy>:<port>` to set up the proxy server for that terminal session
- Run `sudo apt-get update`
- At this point, the update manager popped up and asked if I'd like to install c. 300 updates, which I did
- Restart
- Install `dconf` with `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

  or Using Software Center [image: Install via the software center]
- Run `dconf-editor`, select `system` > `proxy` > `http` and click `enable` (as per the tutorial in teleblog's answer)

And now it all seems to work :)

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial worked for me:

First. You must install dconf-tools in the following ways:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

or Using Software Center [image: Install via the software center]

Second. Run dconf-tool the way:

```
dconf-editor
```

Third. In the Configuration Editor menu select System>> proxy

```
Goto “system >> proxy” change “mode” to manual and select “use-same-proxy“.
Goto “system >> proxy >> http” give your proxy information there and select “enable” option.
Goto “system >> proxy >> https” give your proxy information there, do the same things on ftp part.
Make sure socks have “0” (zero) on “port” and nothing on “Host” field.
```

http://loewyi.com/info/proxy-problem-google-chrome-ubuntu-11-10/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system setting>network.
There you can manually adjust your proxy settings.

Comment: of course i did it.
but it does not work for complete system even after clicking "Apply System Wide" button
For Eg : i am unable to use internet in update manager and softwrae centre

Answer (score 0):

You should export proxy by root user

Just type in a terminal:

```
sudo -s
export http_proxy=http://yourdomain.com:port
apt-get update
```

Comment: `su` doesn't work (and has never worked) by default in Ubuntu, *for becoming `root`*. You need to use `sudo` instead. `sudo -s` is the proper equivalent of `su`.