# Problem prevents the update or installation of new software

Tags: updates

It's been a week now that whenever i run sudo apt-get update it shows me this:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease    Err
http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease    Err
http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease    Err
http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease    Err
http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed InRelease    Err
http://archive.canonical.com quantal InRelease    Err
http://archive.canonical.com quantal InRelease    Err
http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease    Err
http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease    Err
http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease    Err
http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease    Err http://dl.google.com
stable InRelease    Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg 
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666: Err http://archive.ubuntu.com
quantal-updates Release.gpg   Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666: Err
http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg   Unable to
connect to 127.0.0.1:9666: Err http://archive.ubuntu.com
quantal-security Release.gpg   Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:
Err http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release.gpg   Unable to
connect to 127.0.0.1:9666: Err http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal
Release.gpg   Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666: Err
http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg   Unable to connect to
127.0.0.1:9666: Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg   Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666: Err http://dl.google.com stable
Release.gpg   Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666: Err
http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed Release.gpg   Unable to
connect to 127.0.0.1:9666: Err http://archive.canonical.com quantal
Release.gpg   Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666: Err
http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg   Unable to connect to
127.0.0.1:9666: Reading package lists... Done W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch
http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.canonical.com/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-proposed/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease 


W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease


W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease


W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to
connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/Release.gpg 
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/Release.gpg 
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/Release.gpg 
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-proposed/Release.gpg 
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable
to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.canonical.com/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to
connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Failed to fetch
http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to
connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Failed to fetch
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Unable
to connect to 127.0.0.1:9666:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
and when i try to download and install a software from terminal it tells me:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with
--fix-missing?
```

i also tried installing Softwares from Synaptic it also gives me errors of same kinds.. also there is a red triangle on the top right of my screen telling me:

the update information is outdated. this may be caused by network problems or a repository that no longer exists,

now i searched a lot on web on trying to solve this problem so i ran plenty of repositories to see if they work.. but non of them worked..

i checked also my software sources, i ticked or Unticked everything on "other software" tab, but still nothing changed.

this is how my software sources is now:
[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

[image: picture 3]

[image: picture 4]

also this is the body of my etc/apt/source.list:

> ```
> # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted
>
> # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
> # newer versions of the distribution.
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted
>
> ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
> ## distribution.
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted
>
> ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
> ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
> ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal universe
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal universe
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates universe
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates universe
>
> ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
> ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
> ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
> ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
> ## security team.
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal multiverse
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal multiverse
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates multiverse
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates multiverse
>
> ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
> ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
> ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
> ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
> ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
>
> ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
> ## 'partner' repository.
> ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
> ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
> deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
> deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
>
> ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
> ## 'extras' repository.
> ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
> ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
> deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
> deb http://archive.canonical.com/ quantal partner
> deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ quantal partner
> deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
> deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
> deb-src http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
> ```

any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: why are they all ending with InRelease? Those really don't exist. The links are supposed to end with Release. Have you edited /etc/apt/sources.list? It is also quite weird it is trying to connect to localhost, when downloading *.gpg

Comment: i added the body of my source.list to the question, take a look and tell me if i should change anything, thanks.

Comment: looks okay. Please, repost its contents using block quote - it's hardly readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt` seems to be using your own computer as a mirror (`127.0.0.1:9666`). Don't you have/had any software like `apt-cacher` and removed/disable it?

If this is the case, that information should be configured in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or in any file present on `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`. To see if it is set in any of those files use :

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
grep -r proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
```

If you see any information regarding a proxy on those files, just edit it using `sudo gedit <path_to_file>` and comment that section using "#". To have a clue what you should be looking take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/89695/33871) answer.

After this just do `sudo apt-get update` and it should be fixed. If not then you will have to inspect why it is using localhost as a mirror (are you connected to a proxy?).

Comment: i did use a proxy actually, it's name is "ultra surf" and yes it's ip and port is exactly (127.0.0.1:9666) so i went to etc/apt/apt.conf.d and i removed that ip and port of that proxy and saved that file, and then i ran get-apt update and now still the same problem. it gave me the exact same errors, i also ran cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
grep -r proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ but it didn't make any changes, what did i do wrong?

Comment: those two commands are to inspect the apt files to see if proxy is set in any of those. If you still get that then probably you have that proxy defined as system-wide: see System Settings > Network > Proxy settings.