# Update problem please help

Tags: updates

I have got a problem with update and installation.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for salman: 
Err http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Could not connect to localhost:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
```

How do i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You set a proxy on localhost:8080 somewhere, and that proxy does probably not exist. Do you intend to use a local proxy? If not, try `export http_proxy=""` followed by `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Unfortunately 
this didn't solve my problem 
Thank you

Comment: Do you intend to use a local proxy (that is not working), or do you not intend to use one?

Comment: I don't intend to use one

Comment: type `export |grep -i proxy`, does that return something? Also, check /etc/environment for proxy settings

Comment: also, http://askubuntu.com/questions/229369/problem-prevents-the-update-or-installation-of-new-software?rq=1 is related, have a look there

Comment: Ok, great. How did you solve it in the end?

Comment: In network Settings >> Network Proxy
Method was manual i changed it to none 
And it worked :D