# Updating 10.10 to the latest version through a firewall

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, proxy, firewall

I've had Ubuntu 10.10 on my server since I bought it several years back. I've tried to upgrade in the past but I'm always thwarted by my company's firewall. I receive messages like these:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.co/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/main/source/Sources.gz 407 Proxy Authentication Required (Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. )
```

I have my System > Preferences > Network Proxy > HTTP proxy set appropriately (to use Port 80 to get through our firewall.) But still no luck.

I'm looking to upgrade from Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 and I'm really hesitant to install RVM until I've gotten this Ubuntu upgrade successfully completed. Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong / need to change?

Thanks,

Dean Richardson

Comment: The above will show you how to upgrade. On a server it should go smoothly, although you will have to upgrade one version at a time. IMO it is probably easier for you to back up your data and do a fresh install. As far as your proxy problem see http://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I don't think it's duplicate. OP's main problem is the proxy settings.

Comment: @EricCarvalho Well it is a dup of the link on proxy settings then, so IMO both parts of the question are duplicates. See my second link.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Right, I didn't see that link.

Answer (score 2):

Create the file /etc/apt/apt.conf and write this in it:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-ip-address>:<port>/";
```

Then follow [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) to learn what to to next.

Comment: This and bodhi.zazen's suggestions (and the resources you both linked to) worked marvelously. I've successfully upgraded to 11.10 and should have no problem getting to 12.04 now. Thanks for your rapid response!

Comment: Alas, I was premature in my optimism regarding 12.04. Upgrading to that version broke both my ability to download/install rubygems from the web and my connection to my mysql server. :(

Answer (score 0):

For using a *proxy* with `apt` you have to tweak your apt configuration.
See [`man apt.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/apt.conf.5.html)

> http
>
> HTTP URIs; http::Proxy is the default http proxy to use. It is in
>              the standard form of http://[[user][:pass]@]host[:port]/. Per host
>              proxies can also be specified by using the form http::Proxy::
>              with the special keyword DIRECT meaning to use no proxies. If no
>              one of the above settings is specified, http_proxy environment
>              variable will be used.