# How do I authenticate over a domain while doing apt-get update?

Tags: update-manager, sudo, authentication

I am getting various 401 auth errors when trying to sudo apt-get update.
I am connected to my corp vpn and have an SSH into my Ubuntu machine.

How can I authenticate using my network login/pw to complete 1) apt-get update and 2) updates to a newer dist?

::snip::

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/multiverse/source/Sources  401  Authorization Required [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: You are behind a proxy. You question has been answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/89437/134479). You'll also find more information in the [AptGet Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto).

Comment: Sorry, what if I don't know the proxy address/port?  All I know is I am connected to VPN.  Is there an easy way to find the proxy URL and ports?