# How to make apt-get work with proxy?

Tags: apt, proxy

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. When I run the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the error message as:

```
403 forbidden access
```

I have tried the solution I found here in one of the questions, editing `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://mywindomain\username:password@proxy:8080/";
```

but with no luck.

How do I solve this?

Comment: i saw that, it does not answer my problem :(

Comment: @ALJIMohamed I think that  the correct syntax for proxy specification is `Acquire::http::proxy "http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/";`. Please see http://askubuntu.com/a/89695/82650 for details.

Comment: Can you show us more of that error message? From what you posted it is impossible to see if a mirror is talking or the proxy.