# Why can't I install Latex in ubuntu12.04?

Tags: latex

When I run `$ sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base`
it showed the following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgraphite3 libkpathsea6 libptexenc1 libreadline5 libruby1.8 lmodern luatex
  ruby ruby1.8 tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-common
  texlive-doc-base texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-luatex
Suggested packages:
  ri ruby-dev ruby1.8-examples ri1.8 perl-tk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgraphite3 libkpathsea6 libptexenc1 libreadline5 libruby1.8 lmodern luatex
  ruby ruby1.8 tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-common
  texlive-doc-base texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-luatex
0 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 35.0 MB/102 MB of archives.
After this operation, 201 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main lmodern all 2.004.1-5~precise1
Connection failed
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main texlive-binaries i386 2012.20120628-1~ubuntu12.04.1
Connection failed
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lmodern/lmodern_2.004.1-5~precise1_all.deb  Connection failed
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/t/texlive-bin/texlive-binaries_2012.20120628-1~ubuntu12.04.1_i386.deb  Connection failed
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I also tried `$ sudo apt-get install --fix-missing texlive-latex-base` which showed the error

```
naveen@naveen-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo apt-get install --fix-missing texlive-latex-base
[sudo] password for naveen: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
lmodern luatex tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-common
texlive-doc-base texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-luatex
Suggested packages:
perl-tk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
lmodern luatex tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-common
texlive-doc-base texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-luatex
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 48.2 MB/87.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 169 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main texlive-binaries i386 2009-11ubuntu2
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main texlive-latex-base-doc all 2009-15
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/texlive-bin/texlive-binaries_2009-11ubuntu2_i386.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/texlive-base/texlive-latex-base-doc_2009-15_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.

    E: Aborting install.
```

How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: You have a PPA failing (http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/). Try if http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages helps

Comment: @Rmano: It's **not** a 404 error. That question wont help.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? If so, see [how to install packages with apt-get on a system connected via proxy?](http://askubuntu.com/q/89437)

Comment: It's not exactly a 404, but he has a connection failure on the texlive-backports PPA. It's similar... he can try to explore solution there.

Comment: I unselected the texlive links and tried before posting the question, but it didn't work.

Comment: disable proxy by changing proxy method to none on network.And then try.

Comment: @Avinash Raj How can I change the proxy method? If you are talking about 'network proxy' already the 'method' has been set to 'none'

Comment: And also check your internet connection.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Internet is there(Connected through wi-fi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced this type of problem when I choose a custom server for update. If those repository is not available then this type of problem occurs.
First go to `dashboard` and search for `software and updates`. Now change the option like this and select `download from` option to `Main Server`
[image]

Now open Terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)
Type

> `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`

After completing previous operation

> `sudo apt-get upgrade`

and then

> `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`

Now this will keep you up to date to the main repository. Then try your operation

> `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base`

Comment: Thank you, this was the only solution here that worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

1. Update packages

   `sudo apt-get update`
2. Or with --fix-missing option

   `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing texlive-latex-base`

Comment: It didn't work either. I added the output of $ sudo apt-get install --fix-missing texlive-latex-base also.