# i am using a proxy server and i was unable to download any software from ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, 15.04, proxy

i am unable to install Ubuntu restricted extras and VLC and many.
when i use `sudo apt-get install Ubuntu restricted extras` in terminal it is showing unable to locate  ubuntu restricted extras. how can i make it possible

Comment: ...also, the correct package name is `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. No spaces, no capitals!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Read [how to install packages with apt-get on a system connected via proxy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy) to know how to make `apt` work with a proxy.

Then to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` you need to enable multiverse repository by opening Software and Updates program

[image: enable multiverse]

Then close the Software Center to reload sources list.

After update, open terminal and type:

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`
```