# False network problem when I try to upgrade my Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade

When I try to upgrade my Ubuntu appears an error. It says check your INTERNET connection. But there is definitely no network problem as I'm posting this. Help me with screen shots for every step.

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you have? what version are you trying to install?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Make sure you are not behind a VPN or proxy. Also, try the install over Ethernet.

Comment: If you use a proxy then this question may be a duplicate of [How to run “sudo apt-get update” through proxy in commandline?](http://askubuntu.com/q/7470/107450)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can upgrade your Ubuntu:

1. From the Software Updater (from inside the current installation)
2. From a DVD or bootable USB stick with the Ubuntu version you want to go.

### Don't forget to backup your data first!

Looks like you could not upgrade with the first option if understood your question correctly. So basically you could try the second option.

To perform the second option you only need a DVD/USB stick and a ISO image with the Ubuntu version you want to go (the ISO is that file you get when you download Ubuntu from the official website). Then you create burn the ISO into a DVD with Brasero or create a bootable USB stick with the Startup Disk Creator. Now you boot the computer with the DVD/USB stick on it.

#### Recommended resources:

- [Ubuntu Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
- [How to burn a DVD on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)

Comment: m trying to upgrade to 11.04 this is also so old but to get 13.whatever i need to upgrade it first

Comment: @MzeeKing you just said that you want to upgrade to 11.04? It's impossible, because only 10.04.4, 10.04, 12.04.4, 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04 are available for download (http://releases.ubuntu.com/). Sorry, but I could not understand completely what you said on your comment.

Comment: Best advice is Backup then do a clean install. With either 12.04 or 13.04 then restore data from your backup.

Comment: @WarrenHill That's the way I usually do.