# apt-get update with proxy

Tags: proxy, 16.10, ubuntu-mate

I'm using `Ubuntu Mate - 16.10` but when run `sudo apt-get update` I gotta `404` status to everything.

**does not solved**

1. change proxy, graphical and terminal.
2. disable untrusted ppa.
3. re-install system.

**more info**

[terminal response](https://gist.github.com/wwwjsw/43a93807c6e3ba1c640f449cd5cc7b62)

Comment: Oh this is a duplicate of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7470/how-to-run-sudo-apt-get-update-through-proxy-in-commandline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that while you have set the http_proxy/https_proxy environment variable for your *user* you haven't set it for *root* (which executes the sudo command).

Two things you can do:

1. When you change your proxy settings with the Ubuntu System Settings, you have to close current terminals and re-open them so they get the updated settings.
2. Edit your `sudoers` file, using the command `sudo visudo`, and add the following line: 
   `Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"`

That way, your local non-admin user's proxy environment variables are copied over to the sudo environment when you execute sudo commands. This will then apply to any sudo command you run, if that program will pay attention to those environment variables (most do).

You can see a more complete run down here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy