# Attempting to get past proxy issues, why does setting apt.conf not work, but forcing a command through bash with export_http/https set does does?

Tags: apt, proxy

I'm trying to set the `http/https_proxy` values in `apt.conf` so that `sudo apt-get` will work for a proxy that I'm behind.

In `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Acquire::http_proxy::proxy "http://proxy.***.*****.com:8000/";
Acquire::https_proxy::proxy "http://proxy.***.*****.com:8000/";
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, it unfortunately times out saying it can't find the server.

However, when I execute `apt-get update` through this command:

```
sudo bash -c 'http_proxy="http://proxy.***.*****.com:8000" apt-get update'
```

`sudo apt-get`  does work.
I found that command from:
[How to run "sudo apt-get update" through proxy in commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7470/how-to-run-sudo-apt-get-update-through-proxy-in-commandline)

I also tried adding:

```
Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy htps_proxy" in '/etc/sudoers' or visudo.
```

I found this here:

[How to run "sudo apt-get update" through proxy in commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7470/how-to-run-sudo-apt-get-update-through-proxy-in-commandline)

What am I doing wrong?  I apologize for asking this as similar questions were already asked, but I can't solutions I've seen to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your syntax in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file.

Try this:

`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://address.com:port";`