# Proxy is good for browser but not working for wget or apt update

Tags: proxy

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57206176/287948

---

After [this solution using `visudo`](https://askubuntu.com/a/19298/439867) I am navigating by browser...  But `wget` and `sudo apt update` are not working:

```
Ign:1 http://qgis.org/debian bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease
...
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release
  Unsupported proxy configured: 80698092://http
Err:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release
  Unsupported proxy configured: 80698092://http

Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

...
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any URL is valid for browser but not for **wget**, for example:

`wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release` say 
*"Error in the proxy URL  `ftp://myUser/myPassword@http://etc`: need be HTTP"*.
idem `wget http://google.com` or any other URL.

---

### NOTES

The variables are there, `echo $http_proxy` is there and shows

```
https_proxy=http://user:etc%23etc@pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac:8080
http_proxy=http://user:etc%23etc@pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac:8080
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
ftp_proxy=http://user:etc%23etc@pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac:8080
```

My `~/.profile` generated it,

```
http_proxy="http://user:etc%23etc@pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac:8080"
https_proxy="http://user:etc%23etc@pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac:8080"
ftp_proxy="http://user:etc%23etc@pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac:8080"

export http_proxy
export https_proxy
export ftp_proxy
```

(and **I tested before also with** `myUser:myPassword@http://etc` resulting bug)

and it is good for browsers.... But seems terminal have problems with `#` character of my password ([is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57206176/287948)).

---

Try solution with `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80proxy`  (create new file),

but system ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using

> ```
> http_proxy="myUser:myPassword@http://etc"
> https_proxy="myUser:myPassword@http://etc"
> ftp_proxy="myUser:myPassword@http://etc"
> ```

The correct format is

```
http_proxy="http://user:password@hostname:portnumber/"
https_proxy="http://user:password@hostname:portnumber/"
ftp_proxy="http://user:password@hostname:portnumber/"
```

Comment: Sorry I not updated the NOTES (editing), but I tested both and not works... Yes, the correct is your second and now I am using only it.   Seems the problem is the `#` on my password, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/57206176/287948