# How to use apt-get/synaptic behind a proxy?

Tags: updates, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apt-get does not work with proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy)

I use net connection that needs proxy, user name and password,
I can access to the net by firefox, 
but I can't update my system or use Ubuntu software center.

I setup the proxy and username/password in  Synaptic and in Network Proxy
and i edit apt.conf bu this command :

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

but update dos not work

I already did the steps mentioned in the answer about the Ubuntu forums posts.

How to use apt-get/synaptic behind proxy ?