# Setting proxy works for Firefox but not the package manager

Tags: update-manager, updates, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use apt-get/synaptic behind a proxy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38823/how-to-use-apt-get-synaptic-behind-a-proxy)

I'm using Ubuntu version 11.04 I live in a university and we have to give our proxy userid to obtain any internet access.

---

I've given my proxy details in **System Settings -> Network Proxy**  Mozilla Firefox works ok and I can access the internet just fine but now when I try to update it'll ask me to authenticate. In Ubuntu 10.04 when I faced this very same problem I just changed a few settings in the **Administration Preferences** along with the network proxy. Although now I cannot find the area for administration pref.

---

In Ubuntu 11.04 do I need to give the proxy settings in another area other than the network proxy for an update? I've also changed the **Synaptic Package Manger** settings but an error is displayed. The error is:

```
, W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
, W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!