# How to update software through proxy?

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apt-get does not work with proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy)

I am a newbie to Ubuntu/Linux. I am using Ubuntu in office campus and we have a proxy server. I want to update or install new software like flash ,media player, networking tools etc., but I am unable to install from the Synaptic Package Manager.

I have created an ***apt.conf*** file which contains `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.1.6:3128/";` I also have an ***apt.conf.d*** file but its empty and I don't know what to do with this file.

This is the error I encounter when I try to update:

```
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy:3: Extra junk at end of file
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:2: Extra junk at end of file
```

Comment: possible duplicate - http://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy && http://askubuntu.com/questions/38823/how-to-use-apt-get-synaptic-behind-a-proxy

Comment: Could you add the out put of the following two commands: `sudo head -n 3 /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy` and `sudo head -n 2 /etc/apt/apt.conf`? Thanks.

Comment: Note that `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` should be a directory, not a file.

Answer (score 5):

I've created a new file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, named `01proxy`:

```
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://apt-proxy:3142"; };
```

where `apt-proxy` is the hostname of the proxy server. Been using this since 9.04, and It Works without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try using the Network Proxy configuration GUI.

If that fails, add the following to `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

You can omit the username:password, if your proxy server has no password.

[Source.](http://blog.mypapit.net/2006/02/how-to-use-apt-get-behind-proxy-server-ubuntudebian.html)