# Setting proxy for apt from terminal

Tags: apt, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apt-get does not work with proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy)

I have tried changing my proxy settings in a terminal as:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://10.1.3.1:8080
```

and

```
export http_proxy=http://10.1.3.1:8080
```

but when I try to install a new package or update apt-get, apt-get starts displaying messages from which it seems it is trying to connect to a previously set proxy:

```
sudo apt-get update  
0% [Connecting to 10.1.2.2 (10.1.2.2)] [Connecting to 10.1.2.2 (10.1.2.2)
```

I have tried setting the proxy via bashrc file but that din work either. As far as I remember 10.1.2.2 was set using GNOME GUI but I don't have access to the GUI right now so I am trying to set it from terminal.

Comment: you can add proxy in /etc/apt/apt.conf

Comment: @piyush Will that not only allow apt-get to access the web though..? If he wants to be able to access web with anything else he needs to enter it into /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: true, I suggested that seeing him try to do `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: `sudo -E apt-get WHATEVER` works in my case (given that `http_proxy` is already `export`ed as an environmental variable).

Comment: Just a general tip -- when doing these updates, you may need to log out and back in before they start working. That's what I had to do.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Okay just solved it. Adding following line to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` has solved the problem:
`Acquire::http::proxy "http://10.1.3.1:8080/";`

If file does not exist, create it. Do not confuse it with apt.conf.d directory.

Comment: Great. The reason your manual export failed to affect apt-get is because sudo ignores that environment variable by default (i.e. it doesn't pass it on to the command). For one-off runs, you could do `sudo env http_proxy=http://10.1.3.1:8080 apt-get update`. Otherwise, you could configure sudo to allow http_proxy to fall through.

Comment: also if proxy using authentication then provide the details as  `sudo env http_proxy=http://<userid>:<password>@10.1.3.1:8080 apt-get update`

Answer (score 63):

The file:

```
/etc/environment
```

Is the correct place to specify system-wide environment variables that should be available to all processes. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables for details. Note that this is not a script file but a configuration file.

If you want this for the specified command only, use (as root):

```
http_proxy=http://10.1.3.1:8080 apt-get update
```

Comment: Great! Saved much of my time :)

Comment: It is so good. thank you. It is just for temporary usage, Isn't it?

Comment: Alas still not yet for Firefox 37.0.2.

Answer (score 13):

Edit your:

```
gedit /etc/profile
```

Enter the details in this format.

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/ 
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
```

Then run the

```
sudo apt-get update
```

That should do it for you.

As stated above you can enter the proxy into apt.conf (Piyush Credit)

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that I tried setting the proxy via bashrc file and then tried `source /etc/bash.bashrc` but apt-get is still trying to access the old repository.

Comment: Besides that, `/etc/bash.bashrc` is the wrong place to set environment variables as it will only affect bash run interactively. Environment variables should be set in `/etc/environment` or `/etc/profile`.