# configuring and authenticating proxy on ubuntu 12.04 terminal

Tags: command-line, proxy

I am very new to ubuntu, I decided to try it out two days ago. I am using proxy server [41.74.91.139 with user name and password]. I cant access any on-line resources both with the terminal, transmission(to download torrents), or Ubuntu software center.  For firefox, I have configured it and can download .deb and other files but need direct access. 
Please give me step by step instruction as to how to configure and authenticate 12.04 terminal. Thank you

Comment: This is similar to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/158557/setting-proxy-from-terminal) question, try the answers from there.

Comment: @msPeachy [That](http://askubuntu.com/questions/158557/setting-proxy-from-terminal)'s been closed as a duplicate of [this other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy), which is APT-specific. This question here is not APT specific, so while this seems likely to be a duplicate of *something*, it's probably not one of those.

Comment: Use: http://username:Your password@192.168.1.1:3128

Answer (score 1):

edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to have following entries.

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport"; 
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```