# Seting proxy settings

Tags: proxy

I have the proxy address, a user name and a password for the proxy server I need to connect through, but when I set the proxy details under *System Setting => Network => Network Proxy*, only Firefox seems to be able to connected to the Internet.

The **Ubuntu Software Centre** and `apt-get` does not seem to be able to connect to the internet, I have already tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158557/setting-proxy-from-terminal) and a bunch of other things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: you found the right direction. Just add the line `Acquire::http::proxy "http://user_id:password@proxy_server:port/";` in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. If the file does not exist create one.

Comment: next type in terminal `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your system settings --> network, select network proxy and then manual.
Here you can enter your proxy settings, and save them.

After that open up a terminal, open your `bashrc` file in ~/.bashrc and add the following line;

```
export {http,https,ftp}_proxy=http://**YOURUSERNAME**:**YOURPASSWORD**@**HOST**:**PORT**/
```

Comment: Thank you but doesn't work.

Comment: @Michael_K, can you try the edited string i posted? And after that do a restart please?

Comment: Im at a different PC now but will give it a try thanks @remyseroos!