# successful installing packages but dpkg has error

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

happy Ramadan

I'm live in Iran and Some corporation ban us like ORACLE

so I installed Oracle Java SDK 8 manually and after it my "dpkg" has been showing error always.

no different between installation packages. each packages from "Ubuntu Software Center" or "apt-get" install successfully but some error has been shown and I'm very confused and angry

somebody tell me what's wrong in my Ubuntu?

the error is:

```
Package Operation Failed
The  installation or removal of a software package failed
------------------------------------------------------------------
Details
------------------------------------------------------------------
installArchives() failed: Selecting previously unselected package gnome-hearts.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 238764 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-hearts_0.3-2.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-hearts (0.3-2.1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u60-0~webupd8~0) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2014-07-15 14:57:49--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u60-b19/jdk-7u60-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 82.178.158.11, 82.178.158.24
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|82.178.158.11|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-07-15 14:57:51 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u5-1~webupd8~3) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2014-07-15 14:57:52--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u5-b13/jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 82.178.158.24, 82.178.158.11
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|82.178.158.24|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-07-15 14:57:52 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:
 oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up gnome-hearts (0.3-2.1ubuntu1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Processing triggers for python-support (1.0.15) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
 oracle-java8-installer
 oracle-java8-set-default
Error in function: 
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u60-0~webupd8~0) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2014-07-15 14:57:55--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u60-b19/jdk-7u60-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 82.178.158.11, 82.178.158.24
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|82.178.158.11|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-07-15 14:57:57 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u5-1~webupd8~3) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2014-07-15 14:57:58--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u5-b13/jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 82.178.158.24, 82.178.158.11
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|82.178.158.24|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-07-15 14:57:58 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:
 oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: you must provide more info. Which command did you issue to install oracle and which ppa do you use to install it. I don't think you are banned. There are dozens of ubuntu servers around the world. To temporarily fix packages integrity run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: this is my commands: `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java` `$ sudo apt-get update` `$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` i'm in iran and iranians were banned from oracle, don't doubt it !

Comment: Hmm, you use `ppa:webupd8team/java` but it appears that it attemps to download archives from Oracle's servers. So, yes you are banned.

Comment: and what should i do?

Comment: setting proxy may be of help. Look at here http://askubuntu.com/questions/158557/setting-proxy-from-terminal

Comment: try this `sudo http_proxy=81.89.96.89 apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

Comment: In my country all of proxy servers has been banned, I use `Kerio VPN Client` for `Ubuntu` and `SOLVED` my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I download `kerio-control-vpnclient-8.3.2-2261-linux.deb` from [Kerio Download Center](http://download.kerio.com/archive/), (First you must choose `Kerio Control` and then choose the latest version and press `show file` button. In this state download your own version, my version is Linux (DEB))
2. After Downloading the Kerio package Download the related documentation. (my doc is `README file for Kerio VPN Client - Linux (DEB)`) And follow the documentation file.
3. After them, you can use `Kerio VPN Client Linux Ubuntu/Debian` for download any banned packages.
4. Use the below codes for installing Oracle Java 8

   `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

   `$ sudo apt-get update`

   `$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`
5. Congratulation!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your Ubuntu. The Oracle server is replying **403 Forbidden**. The installer is attempting to download from Oracle's servers, which block you because you are in Iran which is subject to U.S. export restrictions. You will need to download the file from another server or country, or use a proxy like Tor to obscure your IP address.

If you have already installed Java, and just want to remove the Ubuntu packages, do:

```
$ sudo dpkg -P oracle-java-*
```

Comment: I run your code but return this error:

Comment: remember:I downloaded `jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz` from a university server and install oracle manually in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` and then run some command that post them in next comment.
but after them the `Ubuntu Software Center` return the above error, why?!!!!!!!!!!! x-(

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java" 1`
`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac" 1`
`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javaws" 1`

`sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java`
`sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac`
`sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws`

`sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`
`sudo update-alternatives --config javac`
`sudo update-alternatives --config javaws`

Comment: @user305703 What was the error from `dpkg -P oracle-java*`?

Comment: Never mind, I SOLVED my problem in my own way. thanks