# Use internet in non-browser application in Ubuntu under proxy

Tags: 14.04, command-line, proxy

I tried a lot of ways like changing `/etc/profile` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file to use Internet for non browser applications.

I want to use the command `sudo apt-get update` but due to proxy I can't. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use export HTTP_PROXY=
```

[Setting proxy from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158557/setting-proxy-from-terminal)

and follow [this documentation on Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-proxy.html)