# 18.04 south African support

Tags: updates

I cannot update ubuntu 18.04 in south Africa. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try [selecting a different mirror](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)?

Comment: I tried that but I found the solution , the university proxy settings were blocking the updates

Comment: Aha! Could you add your finding and how you managed to get around it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in this post : [Setting proxy from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158557/setting-proxy-from-terminal)

the export commands did the tricks for me.