# apt-get not working

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [‘apt-get’ does not work with Proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy)

Everything I try with apt-get fails. I am installing Ubuntu server for the first time. It is version 12.04 LTS. When I run:

```
apt-get update
```

I get `failed to fetch http://gb.whatever goes here......`

If I run

```
apt-get install install build-essential
```

I get "`unable to locate package build-essential`"

I have looked at the `sources.list` but do not know what should and shouldn't be in there.

This is the current content of sources.list:

```
# See help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to 
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution. 
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted
```

Comment: Are you positive you have network connection? Does `ping 8.8.8.8` work? If yes, please post a bit of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Hi, Yes I can ping 8.8.8.8 so think the network bit is ok.

Comment: Here is the sources list     # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

Comment: That works for me. Are you using a HTTP proxy? Could the problem be a firewall? Please try to download the Release file manually, post the output of `http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release` (Note: In order to have formatting, it is best if you update your original post with the output)

Comment: /etc/apt$ http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release
-bash: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release: No such file or directory

Comment: Oops, I accidentally a word, please run `wget http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release`

Comment: thanks pgschk, I'll try to do an update so you can see the response as it should be

Comment: think you have found the problem, the output from the wget is                  :/etc/apt$ wget http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release
--2012-09-05 16:05:12--  http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release
Connecting to 10.40.0.44:80... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required
2012-09-05 16:05:12 ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: Then you should have a look at this post: http://askubuntu.com/q/23666/78830

Comment: I have now added the commands to get through the proxy but it still doesn't let me through. I have added the proxy to apt.conf and also .profile and bash.bashrc for good measure. I know the usernames and passwords are correct otherwise I wouldn't be able to type on here. is there anywhere else I need to put the proxy server settings into?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install -f`. This fixed my problem similar to yours.
You can test it afterwards by updating.

Hope this helps! :)