# v12.10 can't apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, proxy, dns

I know there are lots of questions posed about this, but after troubleshooting for several hours, I'm not sure what to do anymore...

I first installed Ubuntu 12.10 and had no internet access at all. It was running on VMware player with a Windows 7 host.

I was instructed to go into **Firefox>Edit>Preferences>Advanced** and under the **Network>Settings**, I selected *"Auto-detect proxy settings for this network"* and under **Encryption>View Certificates** I imported 2 .crt files and a .cer file and selected *"Trust this CA to identify websites"* and *"Trust this CA to identify software makers"*, and that allowed Firefox to successfully access the internet.

That worked, but when I use `sudo apt-get update` it pauses for a before reporting

```
zackshef@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg 
  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease 
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.184)]
.
.
.
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So I tried a few other things (that I can't post because they contain links and I apparently don't have enough reputation to post more that 2 links...)

I pinged the archive... This went on for several minutes until it reached `icmp_seq_479` (or some number in the 400's), I aborted it, and it said there was 100% packet loss...

It's very frustrating. Please let me know what other information you need to help me get things working.

Thank you!

Zack

Comment: cont'd... I used a Google Public DNS with 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and nothing happened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting proxy for firefox, which is read ONLY BY FIREFOX, and not by ubuntu apps.

Ubuntu refers to system proxy settings, which can be set via System Settings > Network > Network Proxy.

Apt refers to its own proxy settings from a file. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy) provides the solution (refer to fossfreedom's answer).