# Why I am unable to update Ubuntu anymore using the Update Manager?

Tags: update-manager

Why I am unable to update Ubuntu anymore. I keep getting the following feedback:

> Check your Internet connection.
>
> ```
> Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/flashplugin-nonfree/flashplugin-installer_11.2.202.291ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80] 
> Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/flashplugin-nonfree/flashplugin-downloader_11.2.202.291ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
> ```

My internet connections are OK. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you need to update your sources, because the Update Manager is trying to fetch an older version of that `flashplugin` (it's trying to fetch `11.2.202.291`, when `11.2.202.297` is the one found at [security.ubuntu.com](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/flashplugin-nonfree/) right now). Try following the below steps:

1. Close your Update Manager, and open it up again. You should see something like this:

   [image].

   If you do, wait for it to finish, then try updating. It should work. If not, follow the below.
2. Open a terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
3. Type `sudo apt-get clean` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Enter your password when prompted.
4. Type `sudo apt-get update` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Enter your password if prompted.
5. Once it's done, open up your Update Manager, and try to update again. If not:
6. In that terminal, type `sudo apt-get upgrade` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This command is the equivalent of what Update Manager does, except now you look geek-ier.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused when the ppa locations can not be found.

To try to fix this, go to System Settings and click on the Software and Updates link

[image]

Now Click on the Other Software tab:

[image]

If you de-select ALL these locations and try update again it should work **(make a note of the ones that are active first)**.

Once you have successfully updated the system, Start re-enabling them again, one at a time until the update fails, then you can deselect just the ones that do not work.

### Update

If it is caused by the proxy settings take a look at this answer ['apt-get' does not work with Proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy)

Comment: Except the error is not because of a PPA, but `http://security.ubuntu.com/`.

Comment: I saw the answer for this yesterday, I'll see if I can find it again. I made the same mistake then! Sorry... Found the link and have added it to my answer