# No wired connection in 12.04 LTS (64bit)

Tags: 12.04, internet, ethernet

I have installed 13.04 (64bit) and after not having any wired internet, did a fresh install with 12.04 (64bit). The machine was previously running Windows 7 with wired connection working fine. A wierd issue is that normal Google searches (even images!) work from Firefox. Clicking on any links fails, however.

I cannot paste terminal outputs as I only have wired access from the Ubuntu machine.

`uname -r` shows that the kernel is: `3.8.0-29-generic`.

`ifconfig` shows that `eth0` has an inet address (129.11.224.156)

Pinging `google.com` or `173.194.70.101` gives the following result:

> `PING www.google.com (173.194.70.101) 56(84) bytes of data`
>
> `4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3023ms`

Pinging the router is successful:

`4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3000ms`

`dmesg` gives the following output for eth0:

> `tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex`
>
> `tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX`

Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Thanks!

**Update 1:**

Output for `sudo lshw -class network`:

> **Network**
>
> **Description**: Ethernet interface
>
> **product**: Netlink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
>
> **vendor**: Broadcom Corp
>
> **physical id**: 0
>
> **bus info** pci@0000:02:00.0
>
> **local name**: eth0
>
> **version**: 10
>
> **serial** 00:23:ae:65:31:ce
>
> **size**: 100mbit/s
>
> **capacity**: 1Gbit/s
>
> **width**: 64bits
>
> **clock**: 33MHz

Output for `route -n`

> Kernel IP routing table
>
> Destination, Gateway, Genmask, Flags, Metric, Ref, Iface
>
> 0.0.0.0, 129.11.224.103, 0.0.0.0, UG, 100, 0, eth0
>
> 192.11.224.0, 0.0.0.0, 255.255.255.0, U, 0, 0, eth0
>
> 169.254.0.0, 0.0.0.0, 255.255.0.0, U, 1000, 0, eth0

**Update 2:**

Changing the `mtu` to 1472 and restarting the network did not have any effect

Here is the output for `cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback

**Update 3:**

Ok so apparently I need to go through a proxy server. I have followed instructions given here:

[How to Configure Ubuntu desktop to use your proxy server](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-desktop-to-use-your-proxy-server.html)

This has been successful in enabling fullinternet access. I have set proxies following a few instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy).

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you please provide these output? `sudo lshw -class network` and `route -n`

Comment: Hi Peppe, I updated my question. Sorry for the messy outputs.

Comment: Try reducing the MTU `sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1472` and then restart the network `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`. If this doesn't help, provide us this file: `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Posted reply under Update 2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. All I did was go here:
http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin#.UjHYe9K-qHM
and follow the instructions that they provide to download and run the script or you can execute every command that they provide but I think it's just easier to download the script and run it. I'm completely new at this but my issue was resolved after doing this. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Jake, Thanks for the reply. The problem is the script downloads stuff from the internet via `wget` and then proceeds to download stuff from the repository via `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines into /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

To open the file and add the lines, you can do: `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces`

And restart your network: `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`