# Ubuntu Settings (gnome-control-center) crashing after i try to access Network Settings

Tags: 13.10, system-settings, gnome-control-center

Im having serious problems after installing Ubuntu 13.10. I cannot access my network settings under system settings. Whenever i try to access network settings, the settings app crashes off.
This is the output it produces when i run it from the terminal :

```
kelvine@kelvinelove:~$ sudo gnome-control-center
[sudo] password for kelvine: 

(gnome-control-center:4595): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/kelvine/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
**
network-cc-panel:ERROR:rfkill-glib.c:83:type_to_string: code should not be reached
kelvine@kelvinelove:~$
```

How can i resolve this error??

Comment: Try to re-configure it : `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-control-center`, if it doesn't help then try to re-install: `sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall gnome-control-center`

Comment: I tried both options just now...it still crashes

Comment: Give a look at [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1209092) and the related links..

Comment: Is there any alternative fir gnome-control-center?? I need to change my proxy settings so badly

Comment: If setting proxy is your only problem then you can use commands also to set the proxy. [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy) is all about to set the proxy.

Comment: I already know how to set up the proxy settings using termianl, thank you. What i was actually looking for is a way to counteract the crashing problem.

Comment: Please clarify what kernel are you using ? uname -a

Answer (score 0):

You can't start `gnome-control-center` as root. Start it normally and the error will go away.

Comment: I tried starting it under sudo...nothing changed

Comment: No, you misunderstand. No root means no `su`, no `sudo`, no `gksu`, nothing. Just run `gnome-control-center` as your normal user account. `gnome-settings-daemon` running in the background will take care of privilege escalation and everything else.

Comment: Ummm...i tried, still crashing

Comment: Same error message? If not, could you post the new error?