# Change User Profile Photo in UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: webcam, user-profile

Today, I installed the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit. And I open the cheese webcam booth, the webcam works fine. I want to change the user photo in profile, webcam not works. I also try "browse for more picture" and select a photo. But its hangs...

Note: Dafault image  selection works fine

[image: Change User Photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem. User Accounts doesn't seem to detect webcam.

Use Cheese, take a photo of yourself, save it as a file and then add it to your account.

If that doesn't work change your user account photo without using Gnome Control Center ( as seen [here](http://www.faqoverflow.com/askubuntu/61637.html)) by running in terminal:

`sudo gedit /var/lib/AccountsService/users/<replace_with_your_name>`

and change the `Icon` setting under `User` with the path to a 96 by 96 pixel jpg file. Then Log out and in. Your name lowercase as the user folder in `/home` (`tamil` in your case)

Comment: The browse a image also hangs the system.

Comment: In my case works with PNG and JPG, and even allows me to cut JPG. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Do a reboot and try again.

Comment: I try to reboot a system also, not yet succeed

Comment: How it hangs the system? Can you provide more details?

Comment: When i click "browse a more images", it open file manager and select an image which already taken by cheese web cam. system hanged/freezed, (no keyboard and mouse functionality works, i restart the system by clicking the pc button, no way to click shutdown button

Comment: As [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/362540/gnome-control-center-crashing-after-i-try-to-access-network-settings) suggests try running gnome-control-center as root. If it doesn't work reinstall it with `sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall gnome-control-center`

Comment: Thanks a lots. `sudo gedit /var/lib/AccountsService/users/<replace_with_your_name>` cmd works fine...I learned place image in Picture folder and browse it, it work fine...