# Settings crashe when opening

Tags: crash

Summarize the problem
I can't start the Utility app in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. This works only in CLI if I type `gnome-control-center`

Provide details and any research
This morning I tried to change a setting in the share settings to see if I can share my desktop to my tv. I wasa just playing around, didn't change anything. And then going back into the settings, it juste crashed or closed.
It looks like the same problem that has been asked here 10 years ago. But the solution did not work for me. I'm not trying to accesse the network settings, just the setting in general.
[Ubuntu Settings (gnome-control-center) crashing after i try to access Network Settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362540/ubuntu-settings-gnome-control-center-crashing-after-i-try-to-access-network-se)

When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried
typing `gnome-control-center` in the cli provide me with a couple of errors.
When clicking on bluetooth i get this

> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)'
> failed
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value,
> G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)'
> failed
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value,
> G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)'
> failed
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value,
> G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)'
> failed
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:59:04.585:
> g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value,
> G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed

if I click on "Aparence" in german "Darstellung" I get this error

> (gnome-control-center:303146): display-cc-panel-WARNING **:
> 17:00:45.948: Missing property 'ApplyMonitorsConfigAllowed' on
> DisplayConfig API
>
> (gnome-control-center:303146): display-cc-panel-WARNING **:
> 17:00:45.974: Error calling GetCurrentState:
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name
> "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist

If I click on sharing I get this

> (gnome-control-center:303146): sharing-cc-panel-WARNING **:
> 17:01:46.906: couldn't list networks:
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name
> org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing was not provided by any .service
> files

If I click on Diplay Device I get this error

> (gnome-control-center:542205): display-cc-panel-WARNING **:
> 17:03:25.780: no sunset data, using 16.00
>
> (gnome-control-center:542205): display-cc-panel-WARNING **:
> 17:03:25.780: no sunrise data, using 8.00

If I click on keyboard I get this

> (gnome-control-center:542205): keyboard-cc-panel-WARNING **:
> 17:04:26.900: Couldn't finish IBus request: Verbindung ist geschlossen

This is very strange, and I did not change anything, it just came frome nowhere. Can anyone help me fixing this problem?

Thanks

If I need to provide more Information, just let me know

Comment: I can't open the settings panel. Can anyone help me fix this issue? It's not urgent because I don't change much stuff in the settings, but it's not nice, not beeing able to access it.