# installing oracle java jdk 1.8.0_45 manually

Tags: 14.04, oracle

i have downloaded oracle javaSE from oracle website.

File Name :jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar

had used command :

tar -zxf jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm

for extraction.

after this what procedure i should follow to install it.

Comment: your question is answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre

Comment: @gurpreet singh: Before you post a new question, please check out whether some sort of similar questions have already been posted, and hopefully with answers.

Comment: when i execute code mention in above link...i get output as:


update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java doesn't 

What should i do now??

Answer (score 3):

mkdir if not present "/usr/lib/jvm"
download package and type this comand from the download directory

```
tar -zxf jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45
```

install java

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java 100
```

to check if java is installed type

```
java -version
```

if you have multiple java you need to configure it by

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

enter the number you want the default java to be from the list

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Oracle java to Ubuntu is this.
Run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

You will get latest java 8.

Comment: the above code gives below error
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/java'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct

What should i do..please reply asap.

Comment: @gurpreetsingh What is your Ubuntu version? Are you connected to internet?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 and yes i have internet and i use proxy to serve internet.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy

Comment: i have problem in dding only java repository not anything else

Comment: You can't add a repository unless you setup apt to work through proxy. And please ask another question, do not comment here.

Comment: i m able to install other softwares. only problem is with this java thing??

Comment: ok i have realised that its a proxy problem ..bt i work at multiple places where different proxies are used..so how to configure for such