# Difficulties in configure proxy setting on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, permissions, proxy

I am trying to set proxy server using `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf`
and trying to add the commands as in ['apt-get' does not work with Proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy)

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:pass@proxy-host:port/";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://user:pass@proxy-host:port/";
```

When I tried this a message on terminal occurs

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
Error copying '/home/dipesh/.Xauthority' to '/tmp/libgksu-FU5d7j': No such file or directory
```

with a message on screen

```
Failed to run gedit '/etc/apt/apt.conf' as user root.
Unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file.
```

when I manually try to add in `apt.conf` file, it denies messaging

You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.

When I tried this it works

```
sudo env http_proxy=http://<ip>:<port> apt-get update
```

But `sudo apt-get update` or 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3` or

```
sudo env http_proxy=http://10.7.0.1:8080 apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
```

doesn't works.

I am new to Ubuntu please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```bash
# create file:
sudo vim /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80proxy
# with this inside file
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:pass@proxy-host:port/";
```