# How to configure HTTP proxy with authentication on Ubuntu WSL on windows 10?

Tags: networking, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu WSL on Windows 10. How to configure HTTP proxy with authentication on it?

Answer (score 12):

### cntlm proxy for NTLM authentication

I am assuming your proxy requires a [NTLM based user authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager), which will not work with the credentials specified in `$HTTP_PROXY`. A NTLM capable proxy this required for that: e.g. [cntlm](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cntlm.1.html).

#### Install cntlm proxy

The *default* way of installing the proxy would be to use `sudo apt-get install cntlm`, but without any proxy this will obviously fail. You need to manually download the package [cntlm_0.92.3-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cntlm/cntlm_0.92.3-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb) and copy it into your WSL instance.

Install the package with

```bsh
$ sudo dpkg -i cntlm_0.92.3-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

#### Configure cntlm proxy

The `cntlm` proxy requires proper NTLM-Proxy configuration in `/etc/cntlm.conf`:

```
# /etc/cntlm.con
Domain      Domain
Username    username
Proxy       1.2.3.4:5678
NoProxy     localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*
Listen      3128
```

This is the minimal required configuration for `cntlm`. Test and verify `cntlm` with the following command:

```
$ cntlm -M http://www.google.com
cntlm: Starting cntlm version 0.92.3 for LITTLE endian

cntlm: Proxy listening on 127.0.0.1:3128

cntlm: Workstation name used: hostname

Password:
```

If the authentication is successful, generate hashes for the authentication by using the `-H` switch:

```
$ cntlm -H                   
cntlm: Starting cntlm version 0.92.3 for LITTLE endian

cntlm: Proxy listening on 127.0.0.1:3128

cntlm: Workstation name used: somehost

cntlm: Using following NTLM hashes: NTLMv2(1) NT(0) LM(0)

Password: 
PassLM          123456789ABCDEF123456789ABCDEF12
PassNT          123456789ABCDEF123456789ABCDEF12
PassNTLMv2      123456789ABCDEF123456789ABCDEF12    # Only for user 'username', domain 'Domain'
cntlm: Terminating with 0 active threads
```

Add the three hashes `PassLM`, `PassNT` and `PassNTLMv2` to the `cntlm` configuration file `/etc/cntlm.conf`. Then activate the proxy via `systemd`:

```bsh
$ sudo systemctl restart cntlm
```

Now the proxy should listen on your localhost at port `3128`.

#### Configure proxy

Now you can configure the proxy as described in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy) but use:

```bsh
$ export http_proxy=http://localhost:3128/
$ export https_proxy=http://localhost:3128/
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu on WSL. You may need to do `sudo chmod 644 /etc/cntlm.conf` first before executing the `cntlm -M https://www.google.com` command. And use `sudo service cntlm start` to run the cntlm service.

Answer (score -1):

From your bash shell:

```
export http_proxy=http://[username]:[password]@[proxy-webaddress]:[port]
```

and possibly

```
export https_proxy=https://[username]:[password]@[proxy-webaddress]:[port]
```

Username and password are often Windows domain credentials.  If the password contains any special characters, you may need to escape the special characters with a backslash to protect them from the shell. For example, if your Windows account is "gomer" with a password of "Pea$1rzz", and your proxy server is bluecoat.acme.com on port 8080, then you would say

```
export http_proxy=http://gomer:Pea\$1rzz@bluecoat.acme.com:8080
export https_proxy=https://gomer:Pea\$1rzz@bluecoat.acme.com:8080

echo $http_proxy
echo $https_proxy
```

should show the correct credentials.  You'll need to do this for each shell.  So, if you're wanting to do some work with apt, it may be more convenient to open a root shell

```
sudo bash
```

before setting your proxies.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but you suggested the same things as in the https://askubuntu.com/q/23666/283843 I linked already.