# Unable to remove network proxy

Tags: networking, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if Network Proxy is really applied?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3807/how-to-check-if-network-proxy-is-really-applied)

I'd set up a network proxy a couple of days back from system settings. And afterwards I'd set my proxy method back to none. However, my proxy has not been removed.

I know this because:

1. 127.0.0.1 routes me to the index.html file in the base directory of the proxy server.
2. I'm able to access my university internet after hours.

I checked my `/etc/environment` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file and both of them have no proxy details. I also tried resetting the proxy and then getting rid of it but that didn't work either.